# google app engine - Backend Instances being billed

Tags: google-app-engine

We have deployed an application on GAE which seems to have a unusual amount of usage of Backend instances like in 7000 range every day. Even though it's still in development stage and there is not much usage other than a few hours every day by a set of 2-3 users.

What we need help with is in understanding why and how this Backend instances are being consumed? Is there a good way to check it? Is there a configuration or something that we can play with to control it fully?

Comment: you ned to show your app/module(s) `.yaml` configuration files and possibly your `queue.yaml` file (if any)

Comment: We dont use .yaml files as we upload new build using Eclipse. So the default instances taken by GAE is B2 and to change it we use the xml below. In one of the older version we increased the instances and again comment it out in the next version.<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>simple-app</application>
  <module>default</module>
  <version>uno</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <instance-class>B8</instance-class>
  <manual-scaling>
    <instances>5</instances>
  </manual-scaling>
</appengine-web-app>

Comment: You should add the configs in your post. Yes, I keep forgetting java uses different config files :)